# SSRS report parameter not distinct on dataset that is from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

i have a report that uses a stored procedure for it's dataset.

i want to add a parameter on the report without changing the stored procedure. it's on the column trx_status (transaction status) that is returned from the SP.

it can either be "work", "open" or "history".

i added the parameter and used the "get values from query" option and used the field i am filtering on as the value and label selection. however, when i go to preview the report, it lists like 1000 history's, work's and open's.

how can i get the report to just display the three values (select distinct) and show all of each grouping on the report instead of singling out each record?

is this possible to do or do i need to have the SP modified to take the parameter?

Comment: The stored procedure must return the distinct values only. An alternative is to not use the SP and specify the values.

Comment: OK, so if i specify the values, how do i tie the options to the report? so that they actually filter them out? do i do that programmatically in the report?